# Fake background transparency/effects without fixed positioning

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to emulate this effect: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/complexspiral/demo.html on my blog: http://segment6.blogspot.com/

It works, but with one problem: Firefox lags really badly scrolling the page. If I make the background attachment not "fixed", it no longer lags, but the effect doesn't work. Can this effect be achieved without fixed positioning or the lag somehow cured?

I've tried using background-position with percentages but it seems to position based on the width of the element, not the width of the page, so I can't line it up correctly for varying window sizes.

Comment: I've modified the design to use pixel margins instead of percentages, so it "works" now, but I'd really rather use percentages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your complete body content in an additional DIV:

```
<body>
    <div id="content-container>
    ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Then you set the following styles in CSS:

```
html, body {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
}

div#content-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Now it is the wrapping container DIV which carries the scroll bars. Thus the body with the background image will stay fixed when scrolling the content.